# Heroku Postgres: Make existing database follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

As [recommend by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases#high-availability-with-followers) we keep a follower provisioned so we always have a hot standby available.  This is on a lower plan than the main database.

In the last few weeks they have had a number of outages, so we find ourselves making use of the follower:

`heroku pg:promote FOLLOWER_URL`

Then when the main database is back online we promote this again, which leaves the old follower as an isolated fork.

The question is, it is possible to restore the old follower database back to follower status, and if so what is the command?

In the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases#create-a-follower) I could only find how to provision a new follower:

`heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:ronin --follow HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL_URL`

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible, and in any case would almost certainly require that the contents of the database be dropped and rebuilt as if it were a completely new follower database.